# how back to the fragment in the previous activity in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image]

I would when you clicked the button in the red fragment

Go back from the red fragment to the yellow fragment

But I don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you start to activity3, use `startActivityForResult(intent, TO_ACTIVITY3)` instead.
and when you finish with activity3, call setResult(RESULT_OK) before finish

catch the result with `onActivityResult` on activity to trigger fragment1, like

```
if(requestCode==TO_ACTIVITY3 && resultCode==RESULT_OK)  {
triggerFragment1()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recreate Activity2, Start the Activity2 with a bundle having some extra string which indicates that you want to launch Fragment1.

If you want to resume to Activity2, you can use

1. a broadcast receiver or
2. a interface as a listener or
3. Start Activity3 from Activity2 via startActivityForResult() method and pass a result code indicating you want to go to Fragment1